# Using a single command line through php

Tags: php, batch-file

I am trying to run a c++ executable that I have on my computer through my PHP interface. I do not have admin rights on the computer that my PHP is being hosted from and therefore cannot add the appropriate items to my PATH for my c++.

I am able to call the `exec` function in PHP and run my program via a batch file. In my batch file I am able to set my path variable to what I need it to be.

Here is what I am currently doing (with `runVideoparser` being the batch file):

```
exec("C:\\Users\\hewittjc\\Desktop\\runVideoParser", $output, $return);
echo "Program returned $return.";
```

The above works just fine when passing a fixed parameter to my c++ in the batch.

However, my issue is that I need to be able to pass the program different arguments each time. If I run it via batch file then I loose this ability.

So my question is, How can I:

1) Open a command prompt via PHP (I'm running windows)

2) Set my path variable in the prompt via PHP

3) Then, using that same prompt to preserve the path variable, run my program passing it the required argument.

I suppose I could generate the batch in my PHP then run that, but I am seeking any more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can do something like this:

```
$old_path = getenv("PATH");
$new_path = "/my/additional/path:$old_path";
putenv("PATH=$new_path");
system("command -with flags -and args -and such");
```

However, [this won't work](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) if the host machine has Safe Mode on and `PATH` is not in the `safe_mode_allowed_env_vars` directive.